# Remove eye symbol from Windows 7 IE10 password field?

Tags: windows-7

I already read up on the answer as to how to remove the eye symbol (for password peek) from Windows 8. It also mentioned that since Windows 8's launch, the eye symbol also appeared on Windows 7, which is what I have.

The Windows 8 method uses the Local Group Policy editor in `gpedit.msc`, but I don't have that on Windows 7.  So how do I remove it from Windows 7?

Comment: Does it show up in all password fields, or just IE10?

Comment: Which eye symbol?

Comment: @Diogo - I assume it's the `Password Reveal` "eye".  Only on Windows 8 (built in windows programs) and IE10 (7/8). OP - Please update with confirm or correction :)

Answer (score 3):

You definitely can, but you need administrator rights.

**Manual Way**

1. Type <kbd>Win + R</kbd>
2. Type `regedit`
3. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main`
4. The key probably doesn't exist, so you would need to make it:

Add the IE Key
[image: Add IE Key]

Add the Main Key
[image: Add Main Key]

Create a 32bit DWORD
[image: Add DWORD]

Enter the modify menu (right click on DWORD)
[image: Modify Menu]

Set the value to `1`, click okay.
[image: Set Value to 1]

**Automatic Way**

1. Open Notepad.exe
2. Add this to the file:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

      [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
          "DisablePasswordReveal"=dword:00000001
   ```
3. Save it as `DisablePwPeekW7.reg`
4. Double click the file you just made, accept.  Login and verify.

**Automatic Way (Easiest)**

1. Download my pre-made `*.reg` file: [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1502197/DisablePwPeekW7.reg)
2. Double click wherever you saved the file, Accept to add the key.
3. Verify it worked.

---

Tested on Windows 7 Ultimate x64, worked perfectly.

Comment: `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v DisablePasswordReveal /t REG_DWORD /d 1`